# What timezone does MySQL TIMESTAMP columns use ON UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql, time, timezone, timestamp

Does it use the server timezone or UNIX_TIMESTAMP (UTC) ?

And how do I get the current time in PHP, in the same timezone as MySQL's TIMESTAMP columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on your MySQL configuration variables, see [MySQL Server Time Zone Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html).

Comment: That's the most generic answer you could think of! What is the default configuration, or how can I tell which one it is? server/unix timezone. I'm just a simple customer to hosting services so I don't really have full access to the MySQL configuration or installation.

Comment: On my server MySQL uses a unix time but in the timezone of my server, I've verified this by modifying an `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` row quickly after running this PHP script `echo date('H:i:s', time());` and both return a time value that looks like they're both in the same timezone.

Comment: @Jeremy Rudd: I'm sorry that you think my answer is too vague. By default MySQL uses the system timezone, but that may not always be the case (again depending on configuration variables, see `SET time_zone` and `SET GLOBAL time_zone`), it's always a good idea to issue this commands to make sure your application and database are running on the same time zone.